# What is the direction of vector $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}d x \\ d y\end{smallmatrix}\right]$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

Recently I came across a topic " **total differential**" which comes with a result

$d f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} d x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} d y$

As much I learned in multivariable calculus this can be simplified as
$\nabla f \cdot\left[\begin{array}{l}d x \\ d y\end{array}\right]$ which graphically means taking directional Derivative in diraction of $\left[\begin{array}{l}d x \\ d y\end{array}\right]$ But is it  Makes any sense ? someone plese explain

Comment: Assume a functional $f:R\times R \to R$. (dx,dy) is the infinitesimal version of a local step
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_total_derivative_as_a_differential_form

Comment: "is it Makes any sense": please fix the typos.

Comment: But why would that *not* make sense ? Please explain what you find illogical.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the derivative of a function $f=f(x,y)$ is its gradient
$${\rm grad}f=\left[\begin{array}{cc}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}&\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\end{array}
\right].$$

But if $f(x,y)=x$ (the projection in the $x$-axis) then its gradient is
$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\end{array}
\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\end{array}
\right]$

and

similarly for
$f(x,y)=y$ (the projection in the $y$-axis), its gradient is $\left[\begin{array}{cc}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}\end{array}
\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\end{array}
\right]$

Hence the relation
$df=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$
is the relation
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}&\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\end{array}
\right]
=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\end{array}
\right]+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\end{array}
\right],$$
where anyone clearly sees that
$dx=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\end{array}\right]$ and
$dy=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\end{array}\right]$ are the matrix forms of the derivatives of the projections onto both  axis, that is, their gradients, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The direction vector for *any* nonzero vector $\mathbf v$ (in $\mathbb R^n$) is $\dfrac{\mathbf v}{\|\mathbf v\|}$. For instance, if $\mathrm dx$ and $\mathrm dy$ are small real numbers that aren't both $0$, then the direction vector for $\begin{bmatrix}\mathrm dx\\\mathrm dy\end{bmatrix}$ is $\begin{bmatrix}\mathrm dx/\sqrt{(\mathrm dx)^2+(\mathrm dy)^2}\\\mathrm dy/\sqrt{(\mathrm dx)^2+(\mathrm dy)^2}\end{bmatrix}$.

Now suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ so that for small $\mathrm dx$ and $\mathrm dy$, $f(a+\mathrm dx,b+\mathrm dy)-f(a,b)$ is well-approximated by $\mathrm df=\left.\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(x,y)=(a,b)}\mathrm dx+\left.\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{(x,y)=(a,b)}\mathrm dy=\nabla f(a,b)\bullet\begin{bmatrix}\mathrm dx\\\mathrm dy\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $\mathrm df$ really is either "the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $\begin{bmatrix}\mathrm dx\\\mathrm dy\end{bmatrix}$", or "$\sqrt{(\mathrm dx)^2+(\mathrm dy)^2}$ times the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $\begin{bmatrix}\mathrm dx\\\mathrm dy\end{bmatrix}$", depending on how you define directional derivatives for non-unit vectors.

This sort of idea can come up in confirming calculations like the one in the question [About the formula for the magnitude of the gradient of a scalar valued function, |∇T|](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4120877/26369).

Answer (score 0):

The total differential expresses the *linear* part of the variation of the function when you vary the independent variables (excaclty like in 1D). In fact, there is no other possible way, as the *most general*  linear function of two variables has the form

$$a\,dx+b\,dy.$$

Then *by definition*, the coefficients are the partial derivatives.

Comment: It's not clear to me how this addresses the question.

Comment: @MarkS.: I am waiting for the OP's comment to really understand the question.